# Passing / and -- in url it's showing 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: api, security, codeigniter-3, mod-security, mod-security2

When we request to google or any 3rd party API, in this return url we getting this type of code.

```
?code=4/rAERtRkfXf--
```

The server doesn't accept this type code and it's showing **403 forbidden Error**.

When I am talking with server support they told me about the security issue and it's `mod_security` issue.

Can anybody help me to solve this type of issue?

Comment: You need to speak to your hosting provider who can advise what ModSecurity rule that is catching this and how to add an exception to that rule for the `code` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `str_replace('/','%2F',$your_url)` before submitting it to the server